# Passing parameters to zeep client

Tags: python, django, soap, wsdl, zeep

I have this piece of a wsdl file:

```
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <pag:creaCarrello>
     <GestioneCarrelliRequest>
        <utenteApplicativo>YZSMOPMO</utenteApplicativo>
        <carrelloDto>
           <idCarrelloSorgente>11223344</idCarrelloSorgente>
           <itemCarrelloDtoList>
              <causale>prova</causale>
              <codiceEnte>CCIAA_MI</codiceEnte>
              <importo>2</importo>
              <importoImposta>1</importoImposta>
              <importoTotale>3</importoTotale>
              <importoUnitario>2</importoUnitario>
              <quantitaItem>1</quantitaItem>
              <tipoContabilizzazione>TA</tipoContabilizzazione>
           </itemCarrelloDtoList>
        </carrelloDto>
     </GestioneCarrelliRequest>
  </pag:creaCarrello>
```

This is a SOAP service wrote in Java. I need to query this service and I'm using python Zeep library:

```
def soapclient(request):

     session = Session()
     session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password',   transport=Transport(session=session))
     client = Client('my_url_of_wsdl_file.wsdl')

     utenteApplicativo='XXXX'     
     idCarrelloSorgente=11223344
     itemCarrelloDtoList=('prova', 'Datatest', 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 'TA')
     carrelloDto=(idCarrelloSorgente, itemCarrelloDtoList)
     var=(utenteApplicativo, carrelloDto)
     call=client.service.creaCarrello(var)
     var=(utenteApplicativo, carrelloDto) 

     print('variabile del client: ', var)

     call1=client.service.creaCarrello(var)

     print(call1)
```

but I receive from Django the error:

```
ValidationError at /soapclient/
Missing element utenteApplicativo (creaCarrello.GestioneCarrelliRequest)
```

parameters are passed in a wrong manner?

Comment: Can you put the whole zeep implementation please

Comment: updated with all view of the zeep client.

Answer (score 0):

With this example :

```
def soapclient(request):

     session = Session()
     session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password',   transport=Transport(session=session))
     client = Client('my_url_of_wsdl_file.wsdl')

     call=client.service.creaCarrello(
      utenteApplicativo='YZSMOPMO',
      carrelloDto= {
       idCarrelloSorgente=11223344,
       itemCarrelloDtoList= {
        causale='prova'
        codiceEnte='CCIAA_MI',
        importo=2,
        importoImposta=1,
        importoTotale=3,
        importoUnitario=2,
        quantitaItem=1,
        tipoContabilizzazione='TA'
       }
      }
     )
```

Comment: There is an invalid syntax on the row idCarrelloSorgente..it seems correct..any idea?